# Is there anything preventing interoperability between modern languages and COBOL?

Tags: interop, programming-languages, cobol

I was reading about how people were having trouble finding people to work with COBOL when working government systems that still use it. I was also reading about how Fortran, a language made two years before COBOL, is [interoperable with C, C++, R, and Python with the right libraries](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Interoperability).

This allows Fortran scripts to work with modern programming languages to some degree and even create scripts in modern programming languages that can work alongside Fortran code, making it easier for novices of Fortran to work with it. Are there any particular issues that prevent COBOL from having similar interoperability with other programming languages like SQL (which is used for databases similar to COBOL) that would make it easier for modern programmers who might not normally learn COBOL to work with it?

Comment: No, but it is often easier keeping it all in Cobol - saves translation. DB2 has been commonly used in Mainframe Cobol since the 80's

Comment: On IBM Z, C/C++, COBOL, Fortran, and PL/I all share a common runtime and are interoperable.  All can call and be called by Assembler also.  Within CICS, all of these can interoperate with Java.

Comment: *making it easy for even people who are novices with Fortran to work with it*  The evidence from questions here on SO suggest that this is not true !

Comment: @cschneid you should also be able to interoperate with java using JNI in a batch environment (but you might need to use a bit of OO-COBOL).

Answer (score 8):

### Q1: Does anything prevents interoperability between modern languages and COBOL?

### A1: Short answer similar to those above: No, it is actually often done.

But that may depends on what "modern language" is defined for the reader.
Even with "real" COBOL (not some "shiny" [may be read as "blending"] "managed COBOL") you are in most cases free to directly call any C functions so more or less can call anything (at least with a C wrapper) and also can call binaries as you can do on the operating system (`CALL 'SYSTEM' USING 'some-executabe-or-script "param1" "param2"' is a common extension).

For calling into any "native code" directly (like [Win32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) or [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)) you obviously have to ensure you are using the correct parameter definitions, but COBOL 2002+ have stuff like `USAGE SIGNED-LONG`, `USAGE POINTER` and similar (the extension `USAGE COMP-5` is also common in this place).

Additional there are often direct ways to inter-operate with socket servers, HTTP(S), XML, JSON, ... ; and many COBOL implementations also allow to `ASSIGN` a (line-)sequential file to a pipe, allowing to interact with other programs in this way, too.

---

### Q2: Are there any particular issues that prevent COBOL from having [...] interoperability with [...] SQL?

### A2: No, and SQL is a very common directly used in COBOL: `EXEC SQL`

Many people will say that SQL is no "programming language". It is a query language and may be used in different environments, including COBOL.
Depending on the environment used, `EXEC SQL` may be directly integrated into the COBOL environment or with a pre-parser that adjusts the code to be plain COBOL (normally `CALL`ing some "native" code, see Q1).

### Q3: [... stuff] that would make it easier for modern programmers who might not normally learn COBOL to work with it?

... this is a completely different question, whatever a "modern programmer" is.

For a programmer to get to know a programming language it all depends on the programmer and the resources (like time, manuals, tutorials, mentors) - and the will of the programmer. Many people actually don't "want" to learn COBOL (for reasons I've heard but don't understand or disagree), other miss some of the resources (a free compiler is available with [GnuCOBOL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnucobol/), nearly all COBOL compiler have their manuals available online and the ISO working group for COBOL publish the [draft standards online](https://isotc.iso.org/livelink/livelink?func=ll&objId=19468956), too; you often can find mentors in COBOL discussion forums or mailing lists, along with many samples).

One thing that **often** *is* special with COBOL is not the language itself, but the environment it is used on ("mainframe" with job control language "jcl" instead of a GUI to click or a shell to use) and/or the software that is actually coded in COBOL; every software that is maintained over decades has "special ways" here and there, and if you get to "decade old code that wasn't actually maintained for years" you get into even more troubles/fun (this is not something COBOL specific, but with COBOL you may encounter this software more often).

Comment: Good answer! From what this guy says, I think when he says modern, he means programmers who have primarily been working with programming languages from the 1970s to now. C came out around the 1970s (which is one of the programming language he listed in his question) and many people consider the 1970s the start of the digital age (https://www.yourdictionary.com/digital-age).

Answer (score 4):

The scenario involved in the governmental systems is most likely IBM mainframe hardware with a flavor of [z/OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z/OS), [z/VSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSE_(operating_system)), or [z/VM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSE_(operating_system)) operating system.

It somewhat depends on what is meant by interoperability in the sense that most any modern mainframe supports [TCP/IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) and that pretty much opens up the whole networked computing ecosystem to networked interoperability.

My guess is when all is said and done, the reason there is a problem is that the state refuses to pay a market rate for experienced mainframe developers and has kicked the maintenance can down the road as cost-saving measures.

It most likely is not a matter of there being no mainframe COBOL professionals able to make the systems work; it's most likely the state won't pay the  price.

But this is speculation on my part since all I know is that the governor blames inanimate objects for appropriations and management failures within the state IT administration.

As a 40-year mainframe veteran, I'm dying to know details as to how this perfectly good technology is at fault for problems dealing with (again, I  assume) unprecedented volumes of processing demand.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is nothing preventing interoperability.

The main reason (this is an opinion, not based on known facts) that Fortran seems to have more interop out-of-the-box was that there was a free software GNU/Fortran for interested parties to work with.  COBOL was very late in the game getting a viable free software compiler.  That is no longer an issue with GnuCOBOL and people are finally starting to write the code needed to catch up.

Adding to Simon's answer; proof of concept for direct embedding is in a branch for GnuCOBOL; intrinsic functions added to support FUNCTION TCL, FUNCTION PYTHON, FUNCTION REXX, FUNCION LUA and FUNCTION JVM, so far.  With FUNCTION JVM tests for Scala, Groovy, Java, Frink, all worked.  This allows data transfer between COBOL working storage and the other language engine using simple COBOL syntax. Including setups for callbacks to and from.  Those functions are embedded into the compiler and libcob run-time, when using that branch.

For other interface trials, not built into the compiler, but still allowing interop; the GnuCOBOL FAQ has dozens of examples.  Shakespeare?  Yep.  Falcon?  Yep.  C, well, GnuCOBOL emits intermediate C so that's covered in spades. There is also a C++ edition of the compiler, so C++ is also covered, in spades. Javascript; Jsish, Duktape, Spidermonkey, Quickjs to name a few of the trials.

Ada, D, Vala, Genie, S-Lang, ROOT/CINT, J, Gambas, Forth, Perl, Postscript, Pure, Icon and Unicon, Nim, BaCon, SWIG (which opens up many multiples), PARI/GP, Gretl, R, Red, Ruby, Haxe/Neko, Pascal, Erlang, Elixir, SQLite, Rust, Go, more..., including a fair number of esolangs, and GNU Lightning for on the fly assembly modules. Trials documented in the GnuCOBOL FAQ.

Framework interfacing for AWT/Swing, GTK, Agar, and things like ZeroMQ, CGI and websockets also proved successful and are in productive use.  Along with at least 7 EXEC SQL preprocessors successfully tested, and in use.

It comes down to someone caring to try, and writing some glue or properly aligning call frames.  No attempts I've tried have failed to produce satisfactory results, *although Perl 5 was a hair pull of unraveling macro layers*.  (Ok, I just lied, while attempting to embed jq, which relies on using C call and return by struct features, I would have had to leave pure COBOL interface coding, and didn't bother with the C middleware that would have made it easy).  ;-)  Will do that someday though, as jq is quite the powerful little JSON handler.

Use the search engine you mistrust the least and look for "gnu-cobol-builtin-script" and "GnuCOBOL FAQ", and visit the hits on SourceForge.

In my particular explorations I usually focus on languages with a C Application Binary Interface, but other ABIs would be along a similar vein.  It only takes sitting down and writing some middleware or figuring out how to properly synch the call frames.

Are these current samples perfect?  Not always, there are edge and corner cases with some datatypes and COBOL PICTURE data that would require more work, but that is all; a little bit of work and testing to smooth over the bumps.  When exploring, I don't always go that far until an actual need arises. These seed work experiments are just to get some proof in the pudding, all done for the simple joy of it.

One of the lead developers for GnuCOBOL just added uni and bi-directional piping using simple filenames, which provides access to whatever the base OS offers, using basic COBOL OPEN/READ/WRITE/CLOSE (and other file IO) statements. Code was committed to trunk just a few hours before I started typing this response.

Basically, the answer to the titular question is a resounding No.

Answer (score 0):

We found an interoperability problem between C and GnuCOBOL.

Our problem was addressed so this answer is just for educational purposes so you can understand what kind of problems you may have.

The problem manifests when C calls COBOL(a, b) calls C(c) calls COBOL(a, b).

And specifically when the number of arguments varies.

A recent change to GnuCOBOL assumed that COBOL called COBOL so it passed meta data about the arguments in some global area.  Then the called COBOL program cleared out the second argument because is falsely thought it was being called with one argument.  That is, the intermediate C call was transparent to COBOL.

This is under the guise of making it more compatible with IBM mainframe but it caused me a lot of grief.  It was quick addressed with runtime changes.  I would like to see it addressed with a compile time option:

1. Make .so file a stand alone .so file called from any language but programmer has to be vigilant.
2. Make .so file assume it will be called from COBOL and has the additional protections afforded by mainframe COBOL.

BTW: GnuCOBOL is great and has a great community behind it.  If you are experiencing problems report it and you will get better response than commercial products.